# Idiomatic way to tell whether code is on simulator or real robot

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simulation (Gazebo) can differ from the actual robot (GoPiGo3) is particular ways, e.g the number of readings in a scan topic - in my case 360 in gazebo and 720 on Ydlidar X4. So I often have either a constant `GAZEBO=True` or an inline `if True:` both of which are kind of ugly. Is there a more typical way of making code behave a little differently depending on where it is running?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368332/idiomatic-way-to-tell-whether-code-is-on-simulator-or-real-robot/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2020-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a more typical way of making code behave a little differently depending on where it is running?

I would say "no".

And I don't believe there should be one, as ideally your nodes (or other nodes) don't have to realise there is a simulation "on the other side" of topics/services/actions.

If you need different *settings*, which I believe is what you are asking for, then I would suggest creating multiple `.launch` files. For your simulation case, you'd load the `.launch` file which initialises your application with "simulation settings". For use with real hw, you'd create a similar `.launch` file, but then it loads settings which work for your real hw.

In your specific case, you'd have a setting for the nr of points in a `LaserScan` to the appropriate value.

(but I'm not entirely sure why you can't `len(msg.ranges)` or `msg.ranges.size()` instead)

> So I often have either a constant `GAZEBO=True` or an inline `if True:` both of which are kind of ugly

yes, that is indeed really rather ugly, and I would really recommend you avoid doing that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-24**:
I always tell "my" students to treat Gazebo as "just a piece of hw", and don't think of it as a special simulator or anything like that.

You really want to avoid embedding special cases / code paths "for this simulator I always use" in your code, as the minute someone else uses something else, those tend to break.

They also reduce the reuse potential of your code significantly.